# Spring data jpa does not update existing row (Oracle) when using @sequencegenerator

Tags: oracle, spring-data-jpa

New to spring data JPA. I have sequence created in oracle table. I am using `JPARepository saveall()` method to save the data. Inserts work without any problem but when i try to update any existing rows in the table it always tries to insert throwing *unique constraint error* since i have unique index created for that table.

Entity Class

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "generator1")
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "emp_seq", name = "generator1",allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private Long id;
```

Save method invocation

```
public void persistEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
   employeeRepo.savaAll(employees);
}
```

Repository class

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> { }
```

How can i tell JPA to look for existing row before inserting? Any help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: Please post the code how are you *try to update* - here will be the problem...

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I have added the method where i call save. It is just a saveAll JpaRepository method that i am using

Answer (score 0):

In My Humble Opinion;

- Using "Exists" condition-check as "sub-query" for all constrained columns, before Update will solve this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. i am not writing any query, i am using JpaRepository's saveall() method